# Converting HTML table to text using perl

Tags: html, perl, html-treebuilder

I have a html table content which I am trying to convert it into text with same structure,
with the help of `use HTML::TreeBuilder` and `use HTML::FormatText` in perl. I have tried with this code

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use HTML::TreeBuilder;
use HTML::FormatText;
my $raw_html='';
my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_content($raw_html); 
print $tree->format(HTML::FormatText->new);
```

expected output is:

```
data1            data1_value

data2            data2_value

data3            data3_value
```

but the output I get is like:

```
data1

data1_value

data2

data2_vaue

data3

data3_value
```

I am in need of some suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation of [`HTML::FormatText`](http://search.cpan.org/~nigelm/HTML-Format-2.11/lib/HTML/FormatText.pm) states "Formatting of HTML tables and forms is not implemented."

So you will need to find another approach.  [`HTML::TableExtract`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTML-TableExtract/lib/HTML/TableExtract.pm) is a likely candidate.